# LCD monitor's resolution is higher than Laptop Screen resolution , how to get full screen display when Monitor attached to laptop?

Tags: windows-7, display, lcd, resolution

My [Dell U2410](http://www1.ap.dell.com/content/topics/global.aspx/snp/topics/en/ap/in/bsd/monitor-dell-u2410?c=in&l=en&cs=inbsd1) LCD monitor's resolution is 1920 x 1200 at 60 Hz (optimal resolution).

And my Windows 7 Dell laptop's screen resolution is 1920 x 1080.

When I attach my monitor to my laptop I don't get full screen display. Is there a way to get the full screen display on the LCD monitor?

Answer (score 3):

Referring to your tags I guess you're running Windows 7.
When you connect your external LCD screen you might use clone mode. Clone is a 1:1 display of the same contents on two screens. Therefore it is limited to the smallest resolution of all displays attached.
In order to use the full resolution of your external screen you can either:

- Use Extended desktop
- Use one screen only

The first option will operate both Screens independently and therefore allow different resolutions and different screen content on each of them.

The second option allows you to use the native resolution but only on one display (the other one will stay off).

To switch between modes in Windows 7 you can simply press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> keyboard shortcut (the windows key button and `P`). Then select `extend` or `Projector only`.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question but the answer is incorrect. Or better: incomplete.

If the external display is connected via HDMI and there is an Intel graphics card on board (it may also have another graphics card), then you're hitting hardware limitations of the HDMI/Intel implementation. You will not get higher resolution than 1920 x 1080.

Period.